# Why is my object variable empty?

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

All,

I have some code that uses multiple variables, objects and arrays.
Somehow my object which was filled is now empty.

```
var items = [];
var countryCode = "";
var message = "";
var dataset = {};
var countryData = {};
countryData.fillKey = 'NEW';

function getItems(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
             var items = data.d.results;
             for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
             countryCode = items[i].Country0.Column2;                         
             message = countryData.fillKey;
             dataset[countryCode] = message;
                          }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

When I test dataset after this code it's empty. It should be something like:

```
dataset['UKR'] = countryData;
dataset['USA'] = countryData;
dataset['RUS'] = countryData;
```

Why doesn't this work?

Marco

My next code has to use the dataset:

```
var map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('container'),
    geographyConfig: {
            hideAntarctica: true,
            highlightFillColor: false,
            popupOnHover: true,
            highlightOnHover: false,
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 0.5
            },
            fills: {
                'NEW': '#FF0000',
                'OLD': '#FF7F7F',
                defaultFill: '#FFFED9' 
                      },
               data: dataset
                     });
            map.svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

function redraw() {
map.svg.selectAll("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }

});
```

Comment: You're making a web request so it's possible that the request hasn't completed by the time by the time you test the dataset.

Comment: What is happening in this code that makes it 'not work'? What error?

Comment: ajax calls are asynchronous, javascript continues execution before the call completes.  If you check the values of your dataset object right after the ajax call, it'll be empty because `success` hasn't fired yet.  If you need to do something with your dataset just pass it as a parameter after creating it inside `success`

Comment: IrkenInvader,
how can I pass it as a parameter?

Comment: My next code has to use the dataset:

Comment: Create a function that execute your next code and call it in the success callback. There is no workaround for that, it's just that it's asynchronous, so you have to execute your code AFTER the call has finished, hence inside the success callback in your case.

Comment: So everything from var map = new Datamap({ onwards has to be inside the success call?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to the `getItems` function to call once the request is successful.

Here is a short example of a scenario where you need to get items, then do something with that data.

```
function processItems() {
  getItems('the/items/url', (dataset) => {
    var map = new Datamap({
      element: document.getElementById('container'),
      geographyConfig: {
        hideAntarctica: true,
        highlightFillColor: false,
        popupOnHover: true,
        highlightOnHover: false,
        borderColor: '#000000',
        borderWidth: 0.5
      },
      fills: {
        'NEW': '#FF0000',
        'OLD': '#FF7F7F',
        defaultFill: '#FFFED9'
      },
      data: dataset
    });
    map.svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

    function redraw() {
      map.svg.selectAll("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
  });
}


function getItems(url, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var items = data.d.results;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        countryCode = items[i].Country0.Column2;
        message = countryData.fillKey;
        dataset[countryCode] = message;
      }
      callback(dataset);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks,
does it matter in any way that the code is inside the

    $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: I don't think so, you can define functions inside of functions inside functions if you want to :)

Comment: someone suggested to put my next code inside the success function. Is that instead of the callback(dataset)?

Comment: You could put your next code inside the success function but it might get messy.  The callback(dataset) lets you continue after the success function without making `success` too messy

Comment: IrkenInvader,
could you post how that would look as I am not a pro :)

Comment: yeah I'll show you, I just saw you added your next code to the question

Comment: Yes sorry but I am a newbie trying to setup a SharePoint site.

Comment: Just to add another comment. When I place this `code` dataset['UKR'] = countryData; `code` before the var map = new Datamap({......  it works.

Comment: Something like that is what I was thinking.  Replace `'the/items/url'` with the real url

Comment: Couldn't I just use 'url' which is declared before?

`var urlForAllItems = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +
"$select=Title,Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event,Country0/Title,Country0/Column2&$expand=Country0&" +
 "$filter=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event gt '"+startDate+"'&$orderby=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event desc";
 
getItems(urlForAllItems);`

Comment: yep, the line would look like `getItems(urlForAllItems, (dataset) => {`

Comment: Is this code '=>'?

Comment: Yeah that is another way to write a function.  Are you getting errors when you try it?

Comment: Nope, I can't test the code as I don't have sharePoint at home :(

Comment: IrkenInvader,
I tested the code an indeed I get a syntax error at (dataset) => {

Comment: Changed the code:

`function processItems() {
  getItems(urlForAllItems, function(dataset) {
    var map = new Datamap({
      element: document.getElementById('container'),
      geographyConfig: {
        hideAntarctica: true,
        highlightFillColor: false,
        popupOnHover: true,
        highlightOnHover: false,
        borderColor: '#000000',....'

Also added the variables which were left out:
'var items = [];
var countryCode = "";
var message = "";
var dataset = {}; 
var countryData = {};
    countryData.fillKey = 'NEW';`

Still not working. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it. Sometimes things are right in front of you but you don't see it.
Just needed to set async to FALSE.

```
function getItems(url) {
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
type: "GET",
async: false,
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
},
success: function (data) {
         var items = data.d.results;
         for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         countryCode = items[i].Country0.Column2;                         
         message = countryData.fillKey;
         dataset[countryCode] = message;
                      }
},
error: function (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
});
}
```